# How to write Room query to update value in android

Tags: android, android-room

[image]

This is my Table i want to write query so that when we shopping_list_undoo_item if we set 1 for id 60 then previous id 65  whose shopping_list_undoo_item was 1 should set to 0 suppose if we want to update  62  to 1 then 60 id shopping_list_undoo_item value should  set 0 .

**update InStoreShoppingListItemEntity set shopping_list_undo_item = 1 where  id = 19**

using this query i am able to update value of shopping_list_undoo_item but i want to reset value previously shopping_list_undoo_item from 1 to 0 .

Please help how we can write query for this .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
@Query("UPDATE  InStoreShoppingListItemEntity SET shopping_list_undo_item = (id=:id)")
fun setUndoItem(id: Int)
```

- Kotlin assumed

Noting that this will reset the shopping_list_undo_item of ALL rows to 0 (false) except the one row that has the specified/passed id which will be set to 1 (true).

The following **Demonstrates** how this works using an SQLite tool (Navicat for SQLite in this case) *(using just the two relevant columns)*:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS InStoreShoppingListItemEntity;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS InStoreShoppingListItemEntity (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, shopping_list_undo_item INTEGER);
INSERT INTO InStoreShoppingListItemEntity VALUES (19,1),(61,0),(62,0),(63,0),(64,0),(65,0);
SELECT * FROM InStoreShoppingListItemEntity;
UPDATE InStoreShoppingListItemEntity SET shopping_list_undo_item=(id=65);
SELECT * FROM InStoreShoppingListItemEntity;
UPDATE InStoreShoppingListItemEntity SET shopping_list_undo_item=(id=62);
SELECT * FROM InStoreShoppingListItemEntity;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS InStoreShoppingListItemEntity;
```

The first SELECT shows the table when setup with the row with an id of 19 having the shopping_list_undo_item set.

i.e.

[image]

After the first update when the id 65 is passed then the 2nd SELECT shows:-

[image]

The third SELECT is after a supplementary UPDATE this time using 62 as the id, resulting in:-

[image]

It should be noted that this could become inefficient as ALL rows have to be processed.

A potentially more efficient but a little more complicated process would be to have a table to hold the set undo item which would have just the single row (could have more rows) that stores the id of the set item (e.g. 19 then 65 then 62).

Thus when setting just the single row is updated. The drawback being that the indicator per row would have to be generated by referencing the value.

e.g. (again using an SQLite tool to demonstrate the technique):-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS InStoreShoppingListItemEntity;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS undoitem;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS InStoreShoppingListItemEntity (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY); /* Note lack of the shoppling_list_undo_item  */
INSERT INTO InStoreShoppingListItemEntity VALUES (19),(61),(62),(63),(64),(65); /* load the table */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS undoitem (idOfSetUndoItem INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO undoitem VALUES (0); /* no instoreshoppinglistitementity set */
UPDATE undoitem SET idofsetundoitem=19;
/* Note how the shopping_list_undo_item is determined according to the undoitem table */
SELECT *,(SELECT idofsetundoitem=id FROM undoitem) AS shopping_list_undo_item FROM InStoreShoppingListItemEntity;
UPDATE undoitem SET idofsetundoitem= 65;
SELECT *,(SELECT idofsetundoitem=id FROM undoitem) AS shopping_list_undo_item FROM InStoreShoppingListItemEntity;
UPDATE undoitem SET idofsetundoitem= 62;
SELECT *,(SELECT idofsetundoitem=id FROM undoitem) AS shopping_list_undo_item FROM InStoreShoppingListItemEntity;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS InStoreShoppingListItemEntity;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS undoitem;
```

With results from the 3 equivalent SELECTS as:-

[image]
[image]
[image]